# How to analyze memory leaks in Java 8 compressed class space?

Tags: memory-leaks, jaxb, java-8, out-of-memory, metadata

Some Context: We have upgraded the environment of a web application from running on Java 7 to running on Java 8 and Tomcat 8 (64-bit arch, Heap size about 2 GB, PermGen size=256 MB, no constraints on metaspace size). After a while, we started getting the following error:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space

which means that the space needed for UseCompressedClassPointers exceeded CompressedClassSpaceSize. At that moment VisualVM showed a 2 GB metaspace size.

Now with the VisualVM tool, we can see the Metaspace size is constatnly increasing with every request about 3 MB, however the heap does not seem to do so. The heap usage has a saw zigzag shape going back to the same low point after every GC.

I can tell that the application is leaking Metadata only when using a Java JAXB operation, but I couldn't prove it with VisualVM.

The application depends on webservices-rt-1.4 as a JAXB implementation provider. The application uses marshalling, unmarshalling. The class generation from XSD is done with maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.

---

Update:

After tracing class loading and unloading, I found out that the same JAXB classes is loaded into memory by WebAppClassLoader multiple times but never cleaned up. Moreover, there are no instances to them in the heap. I debugged and I saw that JDK is calls the method 
javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext by reflection and that's when the class are created.

I though the classes are cleaned up by GC. Is it the responsibility of the classLoader to clean up?

---

Questions: Is there a way to analyze the metaspace objects? Why do I have a leak in metaspace but not in heap? aren't they related? Is that even possible?

Why would the app work fine with PermGen but not Metaspace?

Comment: You don’t have a “PermGen size=256 MB”, as Java 8 has no PermGen. But anyway, the data in meta space is associated with classes, so the first thing to look for are `Class` instances. Even if they don’t make up a significant fraction of the heap, they might be the cause for growing meta space, if their number is growing and they are not collected. It seems, [JAXB makes it easy to raise such issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3259291/2711488)…

Comment: take a heap dump, analyze it for leaked classes or classloaders.

Comment: @Bassam : did you end up using the singleton option OR did you use the noOptimize flag ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am facing similar issue.

In my case, memory leak was caused by `JAXBContext.newInstance(...)` invoke.

**Solutions:**

- wrap this new instance as singleton (https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/581) or
- use `-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true` VM parameter, like in answer [Old JaxB and JDK8 Metaspace OutOfMemory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255578/old-jaxb-and-jdk8-metaspace-outofmemory-issue)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering why the class loader kept loading the classes again and again. I haven't had time to check the JAXB code yet.

Comment: "wrap this new instance as singleton (https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-581)" Are there any disadvantages to this method ? It appears that the alternative of using "-Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true" is a reduced performance. I'm trying to choose between these 2 options.

Comment: I see that https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-581 gives error message that java.net is down. I'm assuming that this ticket was for the JAXB project. Anyone knows how to read that page contents ? I looked at the current JAXB github project at https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2 -- however, could not find this particular issue, so don't have the tradeoffs of using the singleton options

Comment: @Bassam : did you end up using the singleton option OR did you use the noOptimize flag ?

Comment: @anjanb: The singleton was the best choice , It turned out that the leak existed in Java 7 and older, but we didn't notice it because it was grabage collected.

Comment: @Bassam : Thank you. Can you share your singleton code ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and adding -Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true in setenv.sh as JVM OPT arguments it resolve OOM metaspace issue.

Comment: I am getting Compressed class space for org.jgroups.logging.Log4J2LogImpl.error:Line 95 How can I solve that issue for org.jgroups.logging.Log4J2LogImp